# Changing name of the Anaconda Prompt Window

Tags: python, anaconda

How can I change the name of the window when I open a right click anaconda prompt? Now it looks like C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe, but I want to change it just as Anaconda Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the Anaconda Prompt and you are sure of it, right click on it and select properties, and change the comment to 'Anaconda Prompt'.

[image]